# How to handle a partial payment with a bounced check?

Tags: civicontribute, partial-payments, refund

If someone pays an invoice with two checks (1 contribution, 2 payments), and one of the checks bounces, what is the correct way to record this?  There seems to be almost no documentation on refunds - I'm not even sure you CAN refund a payment that's not connected to an event membership - or if "refund" is even the right workflow.